# Object inside google cloud storage not accessible trough CDN

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-cdn

I have a question about Google Cloud Storage and CDN, I try to access an object inside storage via CDN but sometimes it said it's unreachable [image]

Anyone ever challenge something like this? any idea to fix it? it's a bit weird since sometimes it's work but sometimes it's not.

EDIT:
here what i get if i curl to my object url:

> curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to
> cdn.domain.com:443

Comment: Use tools like `curl` so that you see what is happening. A screenshot of a browser window does not help.

Comment: Your problem reminds me of one I had. I had configured IPv6 incorrectly at my DNS server. Use `curl -v -4 ...` and `curl -v -6 ...` to see if it is an IPv4 or IPv6 problem.

Comment: Ahh I see i will try to only enable IPv4, then update my DNS record

Comment: Please post an answer with details on your solution.

Comment: I forget to mention. Wait 24 hours and test again. DNS changes take time to propagate in some cases.

Comment: sure, I will post the solution after 24 hours if it's proven that there is no problem

Answer (score 1):

Here what I do to solve my problem

1. Go to your google cloud project and open network service -> load balancing
2. Next open load balancer frontend of your CDN delete all ipv6 that already created for the load balancer
3. Open your DNS record dashboard and delete all DNS record that related with  ipv6 that you just delete